# I can't open the virtual device on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, device

I installed Android Studio, java jdk, and everything I have to install, but when I open the virtual device I get an error.

Here is an image:

[image]

I installed **xahm** but I still get this error. Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

I have found same error and When create clone emulator,but when we set ram 1 GB or less than 1 GB the it has been work properly.